# how to get Response for Amazon SNS email notification using postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-sns

whether my invoke url is correct in postman? can anyone guide  me how to get response for amazon sns using postman.i am new to this.
because i created topic arn and subscription arn and even i published message from sns.. it is working. but in postman
i am unable to get response.
This is my url:

https://sns.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Publish&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:591670521916:amazon-sns-demo&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:591670521916:amazon-sns-demo:105fd55a-7bfc-4861-9493-2e9f5ecbec2f

Comment: Please let us know output/error you are getting in Postman.

Comment: <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSFault/2005-15-09">
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>InvalidAction</Code>
        <Message>Could not find operation Publish
 for version 2010-03-31
</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>675188b4-1010-5bf5-946b-defb237480a7</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>

Comment: **version** parameter is an optional parameter as illustrated in the provided answer below. However, if you would still like to use it then kindly check that it's formatted correctly. I have tested the following to be working -> &Version : 2010-03-31

Answer (score 1):

You can use Postman to make API requests (including **"Publish"**) with AWS SNS service as illustrated below **:**

[image]

To make sure you get responses from AWS SNS while using Postman, you'll need to make sure that :

1. You've configured your credentials correctly (by specifying your **"accessKey"** & **"secretKey"** in **AWS Signature** under **Authorization** tab )
2. You are correctly formulating HTTP Headers and body in the **Params** tab

You may learn how to sign and build correct requests using this  [AWS SNS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html) docs

> > If by any chance you are still facing issues, you can update your question with the specific error you are seeing on postman so that we assist you further

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you syumaK.. Now its clear but i have doubts in Authparams passing in the url.. it would be much better if u tell me about this.

Comment: @guru, when using Postman, you don't need to include to the "AuthParams" because when you use the built-in "AWS Signature" then this feature will automatically generate the authorization headers when you send the request.

Comment: @guru, Glad to hear the setup is working. Would you kindly accept my answer to assist other users